# Making a desktop flexbox site mobile friendly

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile, flexbox

I have a desktop site that uses flexbox, but I want to make the site more friendly to mobile users. As it is, the site displays on mobile phones just as it would on the desktop. When the browser window is shrunk (or stretched) the website flexes naturally to its new size. At its tightest size, about 480px, the browser window looks like a mobile website would but as I was saying, on the mobile phone the website is displayed as if it were 1080px wide.

How can I get the website to display on mobile phones the same way that it displays on desktop browsers when the window is 480px wide?

Much thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick this inside your header tags.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```